# Driver debugging on a local machine

Tags: debugging, kernel

Why there is no GUI kernel debugger like SoftICE,  which allows to debug kernel driver on a local machine nowadays? Why remote machine is obligatory for driver debugging in Windows 7 and higher?

Answer (score 2):

An in-system kernel-mode debugger is an extremely complicated software because it must take care of many low-level kernel resources and operations. If kernel internals are changed in the next OS version, the debugger must be updated accordingly. Debugger developers must work together with kernel developers and have access to kernel source code. All that makes in-system debugger development complex and expensive.

And any kernel-mode debugging on the development system is a dangerous and inconvenient process. Even if no FS damages and/or other data losses occur due to a BSOD, booting a development system, starting all required applications to re-create convenient development environment is much longer process than rebooting a dumb target machine (hardware or virtual).

When hardware computers were expensive, there was no efficient remote debugging interface and there were no efficient virtual machine solutions, SoftICE was an acceptable tool. But in the last 15 years, remote kernel debugging in Windows had been greatly improved, so using WinDbg is much more convenient that using SoftICE, even though WinDbg has many flaws and bugs.